# Log4j 2 Adapter for Go

Tags: java, log4j2

We have a log4j 2 server, and different apps need to send logs to it.  Before, we only have Spring apps and the integration is built in. Now, we have some Golang apps running, and they also need to send logs to that server. We tried to send some simple messages directly via socket, but the log4j server cannot pick them up.

Does log4j server require a specific format? I cannot see any error on my client side. I wonder how to send logs to a log4j server from another language like Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does log4j server require a specific format?

Yes, of course.

If you read the javadoc of [`SocketAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html), you'll find:

> SocketAppenders do not use a layout. They ship a **serialized [`LoggingEvent`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html) object** to the server side.

So, unless you implement Go code to write a socket packet in the format of a Java serialized object, you should consider using some other kind of logging server, e.g. [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog).

Comment: You mean I need to convert whatever log message into LogginEvent object in Go and serialize it in someway like json and then send to server?

Comment: @JFreebird No, not JSON. It's serialized in the proprietary binary format used by Java serialization.

Comment: What kind of proprietary binary format?  Can you give a simple Java code example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is actuallly a JSON serialization format that Log4j 2 accepts, and it's more secure. Binary data can be more vulnerable to misuse.